# get your application to speak with custom voice

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech, speech-synthesis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a custom sapi voice for tts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761333/how-to-create-a-custom-sapi-voice-for-tts)

Hey Guys here's a puzzling problem, I have been asked to get one of my applications to talk so it can alert the operator when there is a problem on the machine.  Problem is they want to use a specific voice.

What makes this even more difficult is the fact that it needs to say what the problem is and for one single peripheral there are over 70 error codes and there are 9 different peripherals connected that all need this feature.

I've seen posts that explain how to use the text to speech engine by Microsoft (e.g. http://www.itechgiz.com/2011/01/create-a-simple-text-to-speech-application-in-visual-studio) but fail to see how I can implement this.

I'm guessing I'd have to get their guy to say specific phrases to get the sounds to be able to generate the words but haven't got a clue where to start!

Any ideas, by the way must be C# Win forms?

Comment: Possible duplicates [How to create a custom sapi voice for tts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5761333/323339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jalal Aldeen's comment...

A custom voice is really hard to do... see the link from Jalal Aldeen's comment...

You can use the `System.Speech` classes and tweak an existing voice for output.

Another option - although only for very simple cases (very far from perfect!):
IF every error code corresponds to a specific phrases with no or very little variation then you could just record the voice of that guy (one .wav per phrase/error code) and just replay the right .wav for the current error code... you could even make it a "two-step" process... depending on some condition you play a .wav and some additional information depending on some error-code specific condition (either with a .wav or synthezied with the nearest built-in voice)...